# app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication stopped working after upgrade from ADAL to MSAL

Tags: angularjs, azure-active-directory, single-page-application, adal, azure-ad-msal

I'm running some tests with [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) but unfortunately it's not working as expected.

I had all configured for an ASP.NET MVC (.net 4.6) + Angular 1.6 SPA application with [ADAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) and ADAL Angular. All worked just fine but then I decided to try `MSAL`.

My configured provider's `OnValidateIdentity` handler in `Startup.Auth.cs` was being hit correctly with `ADAL`  and I could add additional claims:

```
Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
                    {
                        OnValidateIdentity = async context =>
                        {
```

Now that I changed to `MSAL` for Angular JS, I'm getting the `ID Token` and the `Access Token` but my `OnValidateIdentity` handler is not being hit anymore.

Is using `app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication` still valid when using `MSAL`?

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
.
.
.
```

Comment: Hey Leniel, what sort of Azure AD setup do you have? MSAL is meant to be used with converged/v2.0 application registrations, while ADAL is usually meant to be used with v1.0 App registrations. Is there a reason your'e suddenly switching over to MSAL?

Comment: Hey Frank... I'm using a B2B AD directory app registered in Azure portal. Do I need to register it using the new portal\way of registering apps for the v2.0? The reason is to try out new features since it's going to be the standard way going forward I guess...

Comment: @Frank: I mean using this new app registration portal:  https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ If I register it there, would my code still work inside `Startup.Auth.cs`?

Comment: Leniel, how was your approach to update to MSAL? Did you create a new project, copied your original project and then changed what would be different? Or did you make the changes on top of the original working project?

Comment: Made the changes on top of the original project...

Comment: Make sure you have installed Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb package in the project. This package is needed for startup detection in IIS hosted applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSAL is meant to be used with converged/v2.0 application registrations, while ADAL is usually meant to be used with v1.0 App registrations,

You should create a new application using the new portal in portal.azure.com if you're trying to migrate to the v2 endpoint. In addition to that these docs go over creating a v2.0 App Registration : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-register-app-v2

Please refer to this resource for more information on migrating from v1 to the v2 endpoint. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-v1-to-v2/

In regards to the specifics of using app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication

> // NOTE: The usual
>   WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticaitonMiddleware uses a
>       // metadata endpoint which is not supported by the v2.0 endpoint.  Instead, this 
>       // OpenIdConenctCachingSecurityTokenProvider can be used to fetch & use the OpenIdConnect
>       // metadata document.
>
> ```
> app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
> {
>     AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(tvps, new OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration")),
> });
> ```

This is referenced from the startup.cs : https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-NativeClient-DotNet/blob/a69a4cb41e821f0ea8dddc937ea401a03e2f49fe/TodoListService/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs

Some more good reading that does a bit of a comparison between the v1/v2 sample apps can be found here : https://simonlamb.codes/2017/02/27/net332-introduction-to-authentication-on-azure-active-directory/